# Is this formula for the time-temperature relation in this universe correct, or is there a more appropriate one?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, time, universe, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm trying to simplify an [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787653/how-do-i-simplify-this-equation-to-the-form-shown-in-the-article) into a form that uses the ratio of the number density of sterile to active neutrinos.

For this, I need a relation between the time and temperature of the universe, the one I found was for during a radiation-dominated period and is (I don't recall where I got this equation from):

$$T= \frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B}$$

where $k_B$ represents the Boltzmann constant.

**Is this the correct formula or is there a  more appropriate formula for the time-temperature relation ?**

*Taking into consideration that it should represent the relation of these variables at a period of creation of sterile neutrinos*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall
$$H \equiv \frac{\dot a}{a}\,.$$
Therefore, if $a$ is a power-law in time, $a \propto t^{n}$, then $H$ takes a simple form
$$H = \frac{n}{t}\,.$$
Also, recall the Friedmann equation
$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho$$
In a radiation dominated universe, the expression for $\rho$ in terms of temperature is simple
$$\rho = \frac{\pi^2}{30}g_\star T^4\,.$$
Using these facts, and that we know $H_0 \sim 70 \text{(km/s)Mpc}^{-1}$ (give or take), and $T_0 = 2.7 \text{K}$, you can work out $T$ as a function of $t$.

Two facts that will help you complete the derivation. The transition from radiation to matter domination occurs at "matter-radiation equality" at a temperature of roughly a redshift of 1000, or in other words, $T\sim 1000 T_0$. In matter domination, the energy density now scales like $\rho\propto T^3$, because the wavelength of matter does not redshift. Matching the radiation dominated solution onto the matter dominated scaling at matter radiation equality will give you the full solution.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But I don't quite understand where the $a=t^n$ power-law comes from. Was hoping you could tell me. Thank you

Comment: This comes from assuming particular relationships between pressure and density in the early universe. I recommend looking into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations

Comment: So, this would make $t^2= 90 \frac{n^2}{8 \pi^3 G g_* T^4} $?

Comment: And because it is radiation-dominated, should this $n$ then be $n=1/2$? As in the wikipedia page?

Comment: That's correct, at least until radiation domination ends. Then you need to take into account that $a\propto t^{2/3}$ in matter domination.

Comment: I've included a bit of extra information to help you match the RD solution onto the MD solution

Comment: "In matter domination, the energy density now scales like, ∝^3 , because the wavelength of matter does not redshift."


I'm curious about where this formula comes from.  It would seem to imply that temperature and volume are inversely related.  But that's not ordinarily the case for isentropic expansion of an ideal gas.  Usually $PV^{\gamma}$ = const for $\gamma = \frac{C_V}{C_P}$.  Why is $\gamma = 1$ here?